# Understanding the use of $d$ and $\partial$ in thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, differentiation, notation, reversibility, adiabatic

It seems a hundred variations of this question have been asked, and it's difficult to find which of those questions relates to exactly what I'm asking. My apologies if exactly this question *has* already been asked.

I am self-studying *Elements of Gasdynamics* by Liepmann and Roshko. In a section on adiabatic, reversible processes, the authors write

> Very important in later applications to fluid flow is the adiabatic, reversible process: i.e., a process in which no heat is transferred to or from the system and in which the work is done reversibly. Then ... depending on whether we choose $v,T$ or $p,T$ as the variables, the adiabatic, reversible process is given by
> \begin{align*}
> de&=-pdv\\
> dh&=vdp
> \end{align*}
> It follows that
> $$
> \frac{\partial e}{\partial v}dv +\frac{\partial e}{\partial T}dT=-pdv
> $$

By manipulating the latter equation, they go on to derive this equation
$$
\frac{dT}{dv}=-\frac{1}{c_v}\left(\frac{\partial e}{\partial v}+p\right)
$$

My question is why the authors choose to write the partial derivative of $e=e(v,T)$ with respect to $v$ as $\frac{\partial e}{\partial v}$ but don't write $\frac{dT}{dv}$ with similar partial derivative notation. Obviously, $T$ depends on more than just $v$, so I would think that a partial derivative symbol is appropriate. My only thought as to why is that in this case, the authors have specifically identified $e$ as a function of $v,T$, whereas they have not made that identification for the other variables.

In a similar equation on the same page, the authors derive
$$
\frac{dp}{dv}=-\frac{p}{v}\frac{dh}{de}
$$
Again, I'm confused why the partial derivative symbol is not used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The partial and total derivatives are different things, but they are related via the Chain Rule:

For $f(x,y,z)$, the differential of $f$ is:

$$df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}dz
$$

If we then divide by $dx$, we can obtain the Total Derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$:

$$\frac {df}{dx} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac {dy}{dx}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac {dz}{dx}
$$

So let us apply this to the case at hand.  Your book takes $e$ as a function $e(v,T)$, and then applies the same differential rule we used above, setting that equal to:

$$de = \frac{\partial e}{\partial v}dv +\frac{\partial e}{\partial T}dT=-pdv $$

Now, technically we can be even more clear by giving subscripts:

$$de = \left(\frac{\partial e}{\partial v}\right)_T dv +\left(\frac{\partial e}{\partial T}\right)_vdT=-pdv $$

Where "subscript $v$" means "at constant $v$."

The authors then divide thru by $dv$, obtaining:

$$\left(\frac{\partial e}{\partial v}\right)_T +\left(\frac{\partial e}{\partial T}\right)_v \frac{dT}{dv}=-p $$

Finally, they use the definition of specific heat capacity at constant volume:

$$c_v \equiv \left(\frac{\partial e}{\partial T}\right)_v $$

And rearrange algebraically to produce your equation:

$$\frac{dT}{dv}=-\frac{1}{c_v}\left(\left(\frac{\partial e}{\partial v}\right)_T+p\right)
$$

except that they omit the subscript which is understood.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed description. I was curious, how would we express $\frac{\partial T}{\partial v}$ if we wanted to? How would it compare to the total derivative in this case? I'm confused because I'm not sure what $T$ would be a function of. Do we say $T=T(p,v)$ or $T=T(e,v)$ or $T=T(p,e)$?