# Thermodynamics double partial derivative for small change of volume

Tags: thermodynamics, differential-equations

In a book I saw this expression:
$$dv = v(p + dt, t + dt) - v(p,t) = \frac{\partial v}{\partial t}dt + \frac{\partial p}{ \partial t} dp$$

I'm wondering what is the correct way to get this result.

I'm guessing I have to multiply
$$v(p + dt, t + dt) - v(p,t)\quad \text{by}\quad \frac{dt}{dt} \frac{dp}{dp},$$
since $$\frac{dt}{dt} \frac{dp}{dp} = 1$$ that doesn't change the expression.

I know that $$\frac{v(p + dt, t + dt) - v(p,t)}{dt}$$ is the definition of a partial derivative, however I'm not sure how to calculate it correctly, especially the $+$ sign.

Comment: See [Appendix: Theorems on Partial Differentiation](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm:978-1-349-21377-1/1.pdf), specifically the discussion starting after Eq. A.8.

Comment: This is also called the **multivariable chain rule** and is derived in various places under that name, including [here](https://sites.und.edu/timothy.prescott/apex/web/apex.Ch13.S5.html).

Comment: Are you certain the expression is not a typographical error?  The correct expression would be $dv = \frac{\partial v}{\partial t}dt + \frac{\partial v}{ \partial p} dp$.  The one you mention in your first equation does not have correct dimensions – final term is $\sim p^2/t$ which cannot equal $\sim v$

Comment: I actually just answered a very similar question https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/728371/313823

Answer (score 1):

I believe the expression you're referring to is

$$dv = \left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}\right)_pdt + \left(\frac{\partial v}{ \partial p}\right)_t dp,$$

where I've correct some apparent typos and added subscripts to indicate variables that are kept constant during certain differentiation steps.

This is called the [multivariable chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Multivariable_case). It's also referred to as *expanding a differential (over its variables)*.

I've linked a couple proofs in the comments; the strategy familiar to physicists is to generalize the 1D expression

$$dy(x)=\frac{dy(x)}{dx}dx,$$

which states that the rise of a curve over an infinitesimal run equals the slope times the run. Put another way, if we zoom in enough (i.e., consider infinitesimal displacements), any curve looks like a straight line. This is equivalent to saying that we'll ignore $(dx)^2$ terms and higher.

We now generalize to the multivariable case. For a function of two variables, for instance, one can imagine a curved sheet $z(x,y)$ (with orthogonal directions $x$ and $y$) that for infinitesimal displacements looks like a tilted plane. The rise in this case is

$$dz(x,y)=\left(\frac{dz(x,y)}{dx}\right)_ydx+\left(\frac{dz(x,y)}{dy}\right)_xdy;$$

again, any curvature (corresponding to $(dx)^2$, $(dy)^2$, and $dx\,dy$ terms) is negligible in the infinitesimal limit. One can continue the series with additional dimensions/relevant variables, although the geometric visualization becomes more challenging.